# Determining non-continuity in Graph

Tags: java, math

I've made a graphing application in both `Java` and `iOS swift` and in both of them I've run into the problem of determining if a graph is continuous or not. To explain further, my method of drawing the graph is to sample points of the function and connect lines between them. 
Pseudo code:

```
func plot(Function f)
    for i=min ; i<max ; i+=step
        plotPoint(i,f.eval(i))
        drawLine(i,f.eval(i),i+step,f.eval(i+step))
```

For continuous functions this works like a charm, but when I encounter non continuity the non-continuous portions of the function will still be connected by a line. Example `sec(x)`:[image: sec(x)]

Here's the Java code within `paintComponent(g)` ([github here](https://github.com/Dando18/DataDisplay/blob/master/src/com/datadisplay/CartesianGraph.java)):

```
for(int i=0; i<ptx.size(); i++){
        if(i!=ptx.size()-1){ 
            if(showPoints){
                drawPoint(g2d, ptx.get(i),pty.get(i));
            }
            if(connectPoints && i!=ptx.size()-1){
                g2d.drawLine((int)(origin_x+(ptx.get(i)*ppp)/x_scale), (int)(origin_y-(pty.get(i)*ppp)/y_scale), 
                        (int)(origin_x+(ptx.get(i+1)*ppp)/x_scale), (int)(origin_y-(pty.get(i+1)*ppp)/y_scale));
            }
        }
    }
```

Everything seems to work fine. My question is how do I prevent the drawing of a line where there is a discontinuity? Is this possible without an algebraic solution? And finally what's the safest, fastest way of deciding whether to draw the line or not?

Comment: Compare the y-values of successive points. If they are too far away from each other, don't draw the line.

Comment: @NicoSchertler that would work in most cases, but for some functions the step would have to be very high too recognize a noticeable distance.

Comment: In the case of discontinuity, the function should return either negative or the positive limits of the floating point number. Maybe you can check that and therefore detect the discontinuous points.

Comment: @Dando18 If that is too imprecise for you, you have to check the function in between two points. I.e. evaluate in the middle and again check the slope. Do this iteratively until you are sure about the discontinuity. You can also use the derivative at the current point to predict the next point. If the difference is too high, do this precise check.

Comment: @NicoSchertler Thanks! I'm going to give your idea a whack at implementation.